# XCode How to set UISlider.setMinimumTrackImage to crop, not scale

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, custom-controls

Im trying to produce custom looking UISlider with a gradient

I would like the UISlider.setMinimumTrackImage to crop the gradient where slider thumb is instead of resizing it.

Gradient image is a png image. At the moment it looks like that

[image: Current result]

and trying to make it look like that, so gradient is cropped and image still keeps 
[image]

Current code:

```
 @IBInspectable var minTrackImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    {
    didSet {
        self.setMinimumTrackImage(minTrackImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var maxTrackImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    {
    didSet {
        self.setMaximumTrackImage(maxTrackImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
@IBInspectable var minTrackImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    {
    didSet {
        self.setMinimumTrackImage(minTrackImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: 4)), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```